# Use of different line style in latex graph

Tags: plot

I am trying to use different line style in my graph, but I am not able to compile the dashdotted or dot-dash line styles. Can anybody faced same issue

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[color]{makeplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}


\definecolor{grisclaro}{gray}{0.95}

\begin{document}
\begin{makeplot}
[startX=1.3, endX=4.01, startY=-100, endY=0.0, Dx=0.3, Dy=10,%
   width=100, heightFactor=0.75,%
   linewidth=1pt, tickstyle=top, ticklinestyle=dashed, tickcolor=black]%
   {\large Scattering Parameters (dB)}{\large $f$ (GHz)}

%Para recortar la gráfica
\psclip{\psframe[linecolor=black,linewidth=0.1pt](1.3,-100)(4.01,0)}

\plotFileA[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=Blue,plotNo=1,plotNoMax=4, linestyle=solid]{100mhZ_bpf.dat}
\plotFileB[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=Red,plotNo=2,plotNoMax=4, linestyle=dotted]{100mhZ_bpf.dat}
\plotFileC[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=MidnightBlue,plotNo=3,plotNoMax=4,linestyle=dashed ]{100mhZ_bpf.dat}
\plotFileD[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=Magenta,plotNo=4,plotNoMax=4, linestyle=dashdotted]{100mhZ_bpf.dat}
%Fin del recortado
\endpsclip




\end{makeplot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! According to documentation, `makeplot` uses the line styles of `pstricks`. It seems that `pstricks` only offers the line styles `none`, `solid`, `dashed` and `dotted`. Regarding the package `tikz`: Do you plan to use `pstricks`, `makeplot` etc, or do you want to use `tikz`, `pgfplots` etc? These are two different options; it probably does not make sense to mix them.

Comment: Like @gernot already said: `tikz` and `pstricks` are two different options. `makeplot` is not as sophisticated in graph creation as `pgfplots` is. So I suggest to take a look at `Chapter 3: Tutorial` of `pgfplots`. That tutorial starts with how to create plots using an external data file, like you are using here too. The package provides ample options to alter lines, colours, tick placement, label placement, etc. In effect: you are in control of the appearance of your plot ;)